# Ajax chamar webmethod com URL amigavel

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net

Não sei se é uma dúvida frequente, ou algo que não é possível.
Durante meus estudos percebi que era possível fazer isso com PHP, mas não vi nada com ASP.NET Web Forms.

Fiz uma URL da mesma pagina:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("Pagina de Teste",
            "teste-usuario.com",
            "~/teste.aspx");
```

Quando passo a página `teste-usuario.com` ela carrega a `teste.aspx`.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho um método AJAX.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "objeto",
            url: "teste.aspx/metodoTeste",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
```

Sendo `metodoTeste` meu WebMethod e `teste.aspx` onde se localiza este método.

Gostaria de saber se é possível passar minha URL amigável (teste-usuario.com) ao invés de `teste.aspx` para carregar a mesma página. Não gostaria de deixar visível o nome da página (teste.aspx).

Comment: Tenho outro documento default, e queria fazer o mesmo mas para varias paginas, chamando pela url amigavel criada entende?

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma regra de reescrita onde sufixo .aspx poderá ser ocultado.

Exemplo (web.config):

```
   <rule name="Append .aspx">
        <match url="^((.*\/)?[^/.]+)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
   </rule>
```

Uma página `http://seu.site/teste.aspx` poderá ser acessada assim    `http://seu.site/teste`.

Na URL com parâmetros, usando como exemplo o script da pergunta:

```
url: "teste.aspx/metodoTeste",
```

Trocaria por isso:

```
url: "teste/metodoTeste",
```

Comment: Já tentei também, acho que esse esquema não funciona no javascript.

Comment: O que eu queria era chamar o WebMethod através de uma url amigavel e nao o nome próprio da pagina.

Comment: Isso sim, porém só queria chamar de outra maneira para mais segurança, mas sem problemas, se eu não me engano no php é possivel chamar através de uma url amigavel ao invéz do nome proprio da pagina.